# Sum of all the iterations of a variable in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 3 To 10

    If Range("H3").Value = Cells(i, 2).Value And Range("I3").Value < Cells(i, 4).Value And _
            Range("I3").Value >= Cells(i, 3).Value Then

        Range("J3").Value = Cells(i, 5).Value

    End If

Next i
```

I want the value of `J3` to represent the sum of all the iterations and not just the last iteration if `i`. Can it be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there are certainly better methods of adding up cells, for your particular method this should work.

```
Dim i As long, lTotal as long    
For i = 3 To 10

    If Range("H3").Value = Cells(i, 2).Value And Range("I3").Value < Cells(i, 4).Value And _
            Range("I3").Value >= Cells(i, 3).Value Then

        lTotal = Cells(i, 5).Value + lTotal

    End If

Next i

Range("J3").Value = lTotal
```

Keep a running total of of your loop, then use the running total as your cell's value after you've finished the loop

Comment: Hi thanks it worked. Can you help me to convert this into a function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53295794/drag-down-auto-fill-for-a-custom-made-function

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
Range("J3").Value = Cells(i, 5).Value
```

To:

```
Range("J3").Value = Range("J3").Value + Cells(i, 5).Value
```