# Drag down auto fill for a user defined function VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the following function:

```
Function myFunc() As String

Application.Volatile

Dim i As Long, lTotal As Long
For i = 3 To 10

    If Range("H3").Value = Cells(i, 2).Value And Range("I3").Value < _
    Cells(i, 4).Value And _
    Range("I3").Value >= Cells(i, 3).Value Then

    lTotal = Cells(i, 5).Value + lTotal

    End If

    myFunc = lTotal

Next i

End Function
```

I want this function to be autofill when I drag it down the column. How can I do that?

[Edit]
Attached is the image.
Consider the Dasboard table as a discrete table where manually entries are posted. Consider log table as a continues table where record of every hour for each date is kept. The entries from Dashboard table get posted to the log table.
I am using this function in the output column in the log table. I want to be able to drag it down to fill the log table.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by autofill? Should it start with the same row as the one you want to fill? Should it always loop over next 7 rows? Maybe it fills cells but with incorrect values? Describe what is your goal

Comment: An UDF only returns something to the cell it is called from. Use a sub if impacting on more than calling cell.

Comment: Hard-coding input cells is a bad idea if you want the reference to change as you drag it down.  Can you tell us what you would like this function to do and why does it return a string if it tries to add a few numbers?  Cheers

Comment: barbsan Yes it should start with the same row as I want to fill. Yes the loop is fixed. I have edited the question to be more exact.

Comment: QHarr cant use a sub as in that case I cant drag it down. then I have to manually make a macro for every row in the column.

Comment: michal yes i agree. i just hard coded them to make the function to begin with as I am new to vba. now that i have made the function and validated it, I want it to be flexible.

Comment: Can't you set up your final table as an actual Excel table with  Ctrl + T so the column with the UDF is autopopulated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why to use a UDF? Don't re-invent the wheel. You can just do that with `SUMIFS`

```
=SUMIFS($E$3:$E$10,$B$3:$B$10,"=" & H3,$C$3:$C$10,"<=" & I3,$D$3:$D$10,">" & I3)
```

Put the formula in J3 and pull it down.

Comment: That can not be used as in that case we have to write 8 different criterias for Sumif in J3 for every entry in the dashboard table. And this will not be possible if I go for more entries.

Comment: @OsamaMalik Well it does exactly what your code does now. I don't see a difference. And I don't see why you would need 8 different criteria. Just pull the formula down it worked in my testing.

Comment: It seems to be working yes. Let me apply it to original data. If it works you just saved my day ^_^. Ill mark tick in a minute